# Is it Possible to access progress bar from first page to second page in xamarin forms?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, progress-bar

Is it possible to do this:

I have a progress bar in first page and i set it IsVisible = false

i created a Dependency method in first page

```cs
[assembly:Dependency(typeof(page.view.FirstPage))]
public interface Progress
{
    void StartProgress();
}

public partial class FirstPage : ContentPage
{
    public FirstPage()
    {

    }

    public void StartProgress()
    {
        //do progression here
          and set Progress bar 
           IsVisible = true;
    }
}
```

and access the method from FirstPage to SecondPage

example i have a Button in second page

```cs
private void Onpress(s, e)
{
    DependencyService.Get<Progress>().StartProgress();
    Navigation.PopToRootAsync();
}
```

then the progress bar in first page will start running.... But my code doesnt work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can use MessagingCenter for this. In your first page, subscribe a message:

```
      public FirstPage()
       {
         MessagingCenter.Subscribe<SecondPage>(this, "StartProgress", (sender) =>
          {
           StartProgress();
          }); 
        }
    
        public void StartProgress()
        {
            //do progression here
            //and set Progress bar 
               IsVisible = true;
        }
```

And in your second page send the message:

```
 private void Onpress(s, e)
{
   MessagingCenter.Send(this, "StartProgress");
    Navigation.PopToRootAsync();
}
```

You can find documentation in [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/tr-tr/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/messaging-center).

Answer (score 1):

> **Is it possible to start the progress bar in page1 from page2?**

Yes, in addition to the answer below you can use [Commands](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/data-binding/commanding#the-icommand-interface) to do this

**Page1.Xaml**

```
<StackLayout VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand">
    <ProgressBar
        x:Name="ProgressBar1"
        Progress="1"
        ProgressColor="Red"
        IsVisible="False" />
    <Button Clicked="Button_OnClicked" Text="Click here"/>
</StackLayout>
```

**Page1.Cs**

```
    public static Command StartProgressCommand;
    public Page1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        StartProgressCommand = new Command(() => { ProgressBar1.IsVisible = true; });
    }
    private void Button_OnClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       Navigation.PushModalAsync( new Page2());
    }
```

**Page2.Xaml**

```
    <StackLayout VerticalOptions="EndAndExpand">
        <Button Clicked="Button_OnClicked"  Text="Start Progress"/>
    </StackLayout>
```

**Page2.Cs**

```
   private void Button_OnClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Page1.StartProgressCommand.Execute(null);
        Navigation.PopModalAsync(true);
    }
```

**Note: It's better to use [Mvvm pattern](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/enterprise-application-patterns/mvvm) to do this instead of this way**